# Blazor throws a System.NullReferenceException on the HeadOutlet component

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side, mudblazor

Repro: https://github.com/VictorioBerra/MudBlazorHeadOutletIssue

I created a new MudBlazor project from their templates `dotnet new install MudBlazor.Templates` followed by `dotnet new mudblazor --host Server --name MyApplication`.

After that I bumped the TFM to net7.0 (from 6.0) and update NuGet packages.

Then I added cookie auth, and `@attribute [Authorize]` in `_Imports.razor` and the aforementioned login component.

Lastly, I added the following `AuthorizeRouteView` in `App.razor`:

```
@inject NavigationManager Navigation

<CascadingAuthenticationState>
    <Router AppAssembly="@typeof(App).Assembly">
        <Found Context="routeData">
            <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                <NotAuthorized>
                    @if (!context.User?.Identity?.IsAuthenticated ?? false)
                    {
                        <RedirectToLogin ReturnUrl="@Navigation.ToBaseRelativePath(Navigation.Uri)" />
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <p role="alert">Sorry, you're not authorized to view this page.</p>
                    }

                    <MudText Typo="Typo.h3">Access Denied</MudText>
                </NotAuthorized>
                <Authorizing>
                    <MudText Typo="Typo.h3" GutterBottom="true">Authorization in progress...</MudText>
                </Authorizing>
            </AuthorizeRouteView>
            <FocusOnNavigate RouteData="@routeData" Selector="h1" />
        </Found>
        <NotFound>
            <PageTitle>Not found</PageTitle>
            <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                <p role="alert">Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
            </LayoutView>
        </NotFound>
    </Router>
</CascadingAuthenticationState>
```

Finally I added the following component to trigger a login:

```
@using System.Web;
@inject NavigationManager Navigation

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string ReturnUrl { get; set; } = null!;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        var loginEndpoint = "Login?redirectUri=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(ReturnUrl);
        Navigation.NavigateTo(loginEndpoint, forceLoad: true);
        await base.OnInitializedAsync();
    }
}
```

Now the code blows up with an NRE on the following line in _Layout.cshtml:

`<component type="typeof(HeadOutlet)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />`

EDIT:

I notice it goes away when I remove the following line:

`<MudText Typo="Typo.h3">Access Denied</MudText>` why?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because You can't render `<MudText>` after the redirect.
Tested with the following 3 pattern all without error.

```
<NotAuthorized>
    <MudText Typo="Typo.h3" GutterBottom="true" Style="@($"color:{Theme.Palette.Error};")">Access Denied</MudText>
    @if (!context.User?.Identity?.IsAuthenticated ?? false)
    {                       
        <RedirectToLogin ReturnUrl="@Navigation.ToBaseRelativePath(Navigation.Uri)" />                      
    }
```

```
<NotAuthorized>
    
    @if (!context.User?.Identity?.IsAuthenticated ?? false)
    {
        <MudText Typo="Typo.h3" GutterBottom="true" Style="@($"color:{Theme.Palette.Error};")">Access Denied</MudText>
        <RedirectToLogin ReturnUrl="@Navigation.ToBaseRelativePath(Navigation.Uri)" />                      
    }
```

```
    @if (!context.User?.Identity?.IsAuthenticated ?? false)
    {        
        <RedirectToLogin ReturnUrl="@Navigation.ToBaseRelativePath(Navigation.Uri)" />                      
    }
    else
    {
        <p role="alert">Sorry, you're not authorized to view this page.</p>
        <MudText Typo="Typo.h3" GutterBottom="true" Style="@($"color:{Theme.Palette.Error};")">Access Denied</MudText>
    }
```

Comment: This is correct. Any idea on why?